# Setting gradle file for google play services

Tags: android, gradle

I m new in android development. I would like to set up my app for receive location updates so I was going step by step by google development tutorial. I created permission in manifest file etc etc... but i have a problem with gradle files. On google tutorial I read that I need put compile

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.18'
```

to my module gradle file, so I have done but can't sync gradle project, it gives me the error:

```
Error(25, 0) gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()' The project 'name' may be using wrong version of Gradle that does not contain a method. The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
```

this is my module gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.example.filip.whereismydevice"
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 23
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),                     'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
complie 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.18'
}
```

and this is my project, main gradle file:

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to              all sub-projects/modules.

 buildscript {
 repositories {
 jcenter()
 }
 dependencies {
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
 jcenter()
}
}
```

So, I'm out of ideas what could be wrong, I was looking for solution on internet, but didn't find the same error. If there is already this problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
complie 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.18'
```

should be

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

Note:

- You misspelled *compile*
- The latest version of Google Play Services is 8.1.0

Comment: damn i m retard... really just misspelled word xD anyway thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find that google play services version? So far the latest version is 8.1.0 so change your line with

`complie 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'`